# Transfer file from SharePoint SPFx to AWS S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, spfx, aws-sdk-nodejs

I have a customer requirement to transfer files from Sharepoint SPFx command set to AWS S3 bucket. I tried using aws-sdk v3 but getting babel error while transpiling the code. Can anyone help in transferring the files either by using sdk or rest api with exampe?

I tried using aws-sdk v3 but not working
Tried rest api from postman and it worked
Same config not working from spfx